# Restricting dashboard access with admin through Prometheus operator

Tags: grafana, prometheus-operator

How to restrict dashboard access with admin without viewer and editor through Prometheus operator

Prometheus operator and grafana

Do we need to modify grafana-ini or org-role always viewer so can we give none?

Or restrict this any other way